# Using a file for input in C

Tags: c, file, input, scanf

I trying to write a program which takes a text file as input and then does a binary search with user input. The problem is, when I compile and run it, the program automatically quits and exits and never allows for user input.

I suspect it is still reading the data file somehow, but it should be running out of options. Any ideas?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int A[100];
char search;
int i, key, len, imin, imax, KEY_NOT_FOUND;
int result;

main() {
// Scan in array length.
scanf("%d", &len);
// Scan in array integers.
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);
}

imin = 0;
imax = len - 1;

printf("Welcome to Binary Search!");
printf("\nDo you want to search for an integer? (y/n) ");
scanf("%c", &search);

while(search == 'y') {
    printf("\nDo you want to search for an integer? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%c", &search);

    result = binary_search(*A, key, imin, imax);
    printf("\n%d", result); 
}
}

int binary_search(int *A, int key, int imin, int imax) {

// Test if array is empty
if(imax < imin)
    // Set is empty, so return value showing not found.
    return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
    else {
    // Calculate midpoint to cut set in half
    int imid = midpoint(imin, imax);

    // Three-way comparison
    if(A[imid] > key)
        // Key is in lower subset.
        return binary_search(A, key, imin, imid - 1);
    else if(A[imid] < key)
        // Key is in upper subset.
        return binary_search(A, key, imid + 1, imax);
    else
        // Key has been found.
        return imid;
    }
}

int midpoint(int imin, int imax) {

int imid = imax / 2;
return imid;
}
```

Here is the text file:

```
10
-144 -1 0 10 75 233 341 1000 8192 57885161
```

Sample Command Entry:

```
a.out < data.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
Welcome to Binary Search!
Do you want to search for an integer? (y/n) y
Enter the Integer: 341
341 Found!
Do you want to search for an integer? (y/n) n
The End!
```

EDITED because answers have not taken question into consideration. Code does not print n found yet.

Comment: where you have opened the text file?What is the value of key? Why you have used `printf("\nDo you want to search for an integer? (y/n) ");
    scanf("%c", &search);`?

Comment: Voted to close. OP is asking about file handling but there is nothing like that in the provided code.

Comment: We might suppose the "file" he refers to is stdin, and perhaps the program (is meant to) works from either the terminal or a file supplied via command-line redirection.

Comment: Edited with sample command entry.

Comment: Note that a) your code asks for a y/n then, if the answer was 'y', immediately asks again for a y/n and b) never asks the question "Enter the Integer:" that your sample output implies and c) reads answers to questions from stdin, which in your sample output was redirected to data.txt, but your sample output implies questions are being read from the terminal, not the (stdin) file. stdin can be the keyboard or a redirected file, but obviously not both at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

Probably your immediate first problem is this:

```
 scanf("%c", &search);
```

%c does not skip whitespace (unlike %d), so if there's
a newline or something in the input that has not been eaten at that
point, then `search` will not equal 'y', and the program will exit.
There are certainly other problems, but that seems like the one
causing the confusing immediate exit. If you use a compiler flag that
asks for as many warnings as possible, the compiler may help you 
find some of the other problems...

Just before you want to read the 'y', you can use a loop to eat up all non-white space characters. For example:

```
while(scanf("%*[ \t\r\n]") > 0)
    ;
```

Then, your program will read the 'y' successfully, and proceed on to the next place it's going to crash. :-)

Of course, this assumes you haven't redirected stdin. If you have redirected stdin to a file, then that file must contain the answers to the y/n questions. If you really want the data stored in a file, but the questions asked/answered interactively, then you're going to need the user to pass you the filename on the command-line, use fopen to open that, and using the resulting handle when you want to read from the file instead of the keyboard.

Comment: See added example of how to eat white space. If you wanted to thoroughly understand why you had "no luck", you could use getchar() in a loop to read and then print out precisely what characters were in the way causing you a problem (e.g., '\r'). However, life will generally be easier if you just use *some* technique for eating white space before trying to scanf with a %c.

Comment: @Ron Burk  Why not simply `scanf(" %c", &search);`?

Comment: @chux Yes, that's probably a better/briefer answer. But since I don't know off the top of my head precisely how "whitespace" is defined (does it match '\r' under *nix? under all versions of C standard?) the longer way should by-gum work, which is sometimes more important than brevity when someone is bewildered by many things not working.

Comment: @Ron Burk C11dr 7.4.1.10 defines white-space, it is locale specific and `scanf(" %c"` uses that.  This answer uses a program specific definition of white-space.   Neither do I know off the top of my head which `char` are whitespace, but I do not need to know.  By using `" "` in `scanf()` or `isspace()`, I use the same white-space definition that matches compiler's and run-time view of white-space.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your program won't wait for user input. Add `getchar();` at the end of `main()` or slightly modify scanf:

```cpp
printf("\nDo you want to search for an integer? (y/n) ");
scanf(" %c", &search);
     //^ added space
```

Next, your program is not reading file - implement it as mentioned above/below.

Comment: I know scanf can be used with pipes. So I should be able to run a.exe < data.txt ... I have a working program that does this.

I added the space, I've had troubles with that before but it didn't help. =/

Answer (score 0):

To read from a file in C you should use something like that :

```
FILE *inputfile;
char *mode = "r"; //we use r because you just want to read file
inputfile = fopen("YOURFILENAME", mode);
```

after that you can use "fscanf" function to read values from your file :

```
fscanf(inputfile, "%d", &len);
```

and after finish reading from file just write :

```
fclose(inputfile);
```

Comment: I replaced this code with my scanf and for loop for scanning (and added in a scan for the array).

The program compiles and runs but it does not display anything.

Comment: try to print what you read from file. If they are true, you should check your binary search function. Details of reading from file is well written on this site you can check [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/)